# this.props.route.params returns value as undefined

Tags: firebase, react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-firebase

I'm building a barcode reader app that scans that qr code and then takes data and is used as a key to fetch an object from firebase. In order the data to be used as a key I need to pass through another screen but when I check console log it's cameback that the scanned key is undefined.

The itself barcode scanner works perfectly.
Barcode class :

```js
export  class BarCodeScannerScreen extends Component{
   

  state = {
    CameraPermissionGranted: null,  
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    // Ask for camera permission
    const { status } = await Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.CAMERA);
    this.setState({ CameraPermissionGranted: status === "granted" ? true : false });
  
    
  };
  

  barCodeScanned = ({ data }) => {
    //Access the Data
        
        alert(data); // shows the scanned key
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Info', {
          item: data, }); // but then it's dissapears in here.
        
  };

  render(){
      
    const { CameraPermissionGranted } = this.state;
    if(CameraPermissionGranted === null){
      // Request Permission
      return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <Text>Please grant Camera permission</Text>
        </View> 
      );
    }
    if(CameraPermissionGranted === false){
        // Permission denied
      return ( 
        <View style={styles.container}>
         <Text>Camera Permission Denied.</Text>
        </View> 
      );
    }
    if(CameraPermissionGranted === true){
      // Got the permission, time to scan
      return (
        <View style = {{
            flex: 1,
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
          <BarCodeScanner
          onBarCodeScanned = {this.barCodeScanned }
          style = {{
              height:  DEVICE_HEIGHT/1.1,
              width: DEVICE_WIDTH,
          }}
          >
          </BarCodeScanner>
        </View>
      );
      
    }
  }
      
}
```

Here is my Info screen that receives the information :

```js
export default class InfoScreen extends Component {
  
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={ 
        productlist:[],
        scannedkey: this.props.route.params.item

        
        } }
        
    async componentDidMount(){
     
  
        
        firebase.database().ref(`product/${ this.state.scannedkey}`).on(
          "value",
          (snapshot) => {
            var list = [];
            snapshot.forEach((child) => {
              list.push({
                key: child.key,
                title: child.val().title,
                //details: child.val().details,
                //price: child.val().price
              });
            });
        
            this.setState({ productlist: list });
          },
          (error) => console.error(error)
        );
    }
  componentWillUnmount() {
      if (this.valuelistener_) {
        this.valueRef_.off("value", this.valuelistener_)
      }}
    
  render() {
    console.log(this.state.scannedkey); // console log shows that scanned key is undefined
 return(
     <View style={styles.container}>
       <Text>Hey</Text>
       
      <Text>{this.state.productlist.title}</Text>
     </View>
 );}}
```

App.js

```js
export default function App() {
  const Drawer=createDrawerNavigator();
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
    <NavigationContainer>
    <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Barcode">
       
      <Drawer.Screen name="Barcode" component={BarCodeScannerScreen} />
      <Drawer.Screen name="Info" component={InfoScreen} />
  

    </Drawer.Navigator>
    
  </NavigationContainer>
  </Provider>

   
  );
}
```

I ussualy use function components to navigate through but with class components it's a little tricky for me. Perhaps I missed something?

So far I 've tried :

```js
this.props.navigation.navigate('Info', {
          item: JSON.stringify(data)  , });
```

And it didn't work.
I will be grateful for your help.

Comment: Is InfoScreen a top level component or a Component you use inside another component?

Comment: @voxtool I apologize if I misunderstood your question but I'm not exactly advanced in React - native and I also this basicaly first time dealing with class components. My aim is Scan the qr code in Barcode component and navigate to InfoScreen with the data (it's navigates but without data) inside of App.js. I included App.js file perhaps it's will give you more clarity. Please do tell me if I need to reaproach on how I should handle navigation.

Comment: You have a typo this.props.route.params.itemID, I think you are expecting item, not itemID

Comment: @lissettdm Sorry forgot to edit out, but the issue still remains.

Comment: You are trying to get a thing that doesn't exist. route.params is refered to things stored inside an url. By looking at the way you pass the data you should be able to access it with   **this.props.item** in InfoScreen

Comment: I tried to access it but it's still returned undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try to use item directly from props, not from state

in your componentDidMount call where you supply from state the scannedKey, supply it from props

```
 firebase.database().ref(`product/${this.props.route.params.item}`)....
```

you are also calling **this.props** instead of **props** directly in your state inside your constructor, which have direct access to it, that's why you can call **super(props)** and not **super(this.props)**,  I am not sure if this is the issue, but in react docs says don't copy props to state because they get ignored, and it's bad practice my friend.

check this link, in the big yellow note what I am reffering to
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#constructor

Comment: I tried to supply it from props but still undefined

Comment: You are passing data correctly from the first screen. Try to switch to functional component in the Info screen and try to read params like before or try this second way seems to be the correct for Class Component like this:    this.props.navigation.getParam(paramName, defaultValue)